# Invalid API key as a reponse of PUT method using RESTServer codeigniter

Tags: php, postman, codeigniter-restserver

I am using the codeigniter rest server api library.

When I enter http://localhost/RESTapi/api/question?X-API-KEY=XXX in Postman with the PUT method 
I'm getting:
{
  "status": false,
  "error": "Invalid API key "
}

It works fine with GET method 
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen some API's that do not look at the GET params if you make a POST or PUT request for credentials or are inconsistent in how they do it.

Really, credentials should go in headers either via the Authorize header or a custom one for many reasons like 'not logging credentials to access logs', but I digress.

In this case you can try:

- Put (no pun) the `X-API-KEY=XXX` inside the body of the `PUT` just to see if this works
- See if/how the library accepts the API key in a header

Looking at this library in particular (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver), they do support the header `X-API-KEY`.  This should be where you put the key for ALL requests--it's best practice not to pass them as url params.

Here's the commandline example using curl from their Github project.

```
 curl -X POST -H "X-API-KEY: some_key_here" http://example.com/books
```

In PHP you can use curl to set header like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-API-KEY: XXX'));
```

Comment: i tried to pass the api key in header from Postman and it works, thanks a lot!